# TFS build does not apply the value of $(VSInstallDir) macros

Tags: tfs, msbuild, macros

I have a build-machine and I have made simple changes recently to run *editbin.exe* tool with *LARGEADDRESSAWARE* parameter right after each building. The tool is located in *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin* (of course, the path can be another). And I have added new target to the build.proj file:

```
<Exec command="&quot;$(VSInstallDir)\VC\bin\editbin.exe&quot; /LARGEADDRESSAWARE &quot;Manager.exe&quot;"/>
```

If I run MS Build locally on the build machine it works properly. Good! But after any checkin build is not able to be completed with the following error:
**The command ""\VC\bin\editbin.exe"" exited with code 3**. As I understand TFS build does not apply the value of $(VSInstallDir) macros (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\ in my case). Any suggesting?

Comment: Are you using TFS 2013?

Comment: @Cece Yes, namely 2013

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the problem I did the next: In VS build config: Process->Build process parameters->5. Advances->MSBuild arguments added /p:VSInstallDir = Value